# Yum does not resolve new package dependencies on local upgrade

Tags: centos7, yum, rpmbuild

I have an RPM package `mypackge` and recent changes my software have required me to add OpenSSL v1.0.2 as a dependency.

Initially the RPM spec contained the following requires line:

```
Requires: openssl policycoreutils-python python2-pip ...
```

I have updated this line to:

```
Requires: openssl >= 1.0.2 policycoreutils-python python2-pip ...
```

This seems to work perfectly for new installs, the new dependency is resolved and installed as expected. The problem comes when I try to update an existing installation...

```
[root@vm]# yum install mypackage-1.2.1.4-1.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Examining mypackage-1.2.1.4-1.x86_64.rpm: mypackage-1.2.1.4-1.x86_64
Marking mypackage-1.2.1.4-1.x86_64.rpm as an update to mypackage-1.2.1.3-1.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mypackage-1.2.1.3-1 will be updated
---> Package mypackage-1.2.1.4-1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
===========================================================================
Package    Arch    Version    Repository                            Size
===========================================================================
Updating:
mypackage  x86_64  1.2.1.4-1  /mypackage-1.2.1.4-1.x86_64.rpm       5.0 M

Transaction Summary
===========================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package
```

For some reason the new OpenSSL dependency is not resolved or installed, is this expected behavior and if so how should I go about adding additional dependencies to existing software packages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not expected behavior. Which openssl is installed on the machine where you run? Maybe the new openssl is already present? Try also to see what openssl provides: `rpm -q openssl --provides`

Comment: ah right; on a new machine where openssl is not yet installed; yum will always take the most recent version of the package if it can.

Comment: Installed openssl is 1.0.1, output of --provides is `openssl = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7` and `openssl(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-60.el7`

Comment: For what it is worth this is a completely clean installation of CentOS 7.4 with only my original package and its dependencies installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is linked to **epoch** numbering. Your version requires `openssl >= 1.0.2`. However the openssl package provides `1:1.0.1`. The **epoch** number is the most important number. In fact rpm read your requirement `openssl >= 1.0.2` as `openssl >= 0:1.0.2`.

Your problem will be solved if you say:

```
Requires: openssl >= 1:1.0.2
```

*NOTE* : when you make a clean install and openssl was not yet installed; yum takes the latest version by default; which tricked you into thinking that your requirement worked.

for further reading; look [here](http://rpm5.org/docs/rpm-guide.html#id3029264)

Comment: Brilliant this works for me perfectly thanks! I guess my only confusion now is why does this work on a clean install (openssl 1.0.1e is installed by default on the CentOS distro I have)?